# How to get the remaining axis of a 3d vector knowing the other two?

Tags: c++, c, math

I need to get the remaining value of a 3d vector "v[3]"

I have a function that returns the remaining axis having the other two as parameters:

```
static get_remain_axis(const short a, const short b) {
    if (a == 0) {
        if (b == 1)
            return 2;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    else if (a == 1) {
        if (b == 0)
            return 2;
        else
            return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (b == 0)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    }
}
```

So I could do so:

```
v[get_remain_axis(a, b)]
```

But I need efficiency in this operation, and if possible, it would be nice if it were atomic.

How to do this function more efficiently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At least as I read things, you have axes `0`, `1` and `2`. The inputs are two of those, and you want to return the third one.

Assuming that's the case, the three numbers need to add up to 3, so you can just do: `return 3 - (a + b);`

Comment: can `3 ^ (a | b)` be any faster?

Comment: @Ap31: I suppose there could (at least theoretically) be a processor on which it would be (but at least on the *vast* majority of processors, it would make no difference).